# How to multiply constraint variables in a IBM CPLEX MILP file?

Tags: variables, constraints, multiplication, cplex, quadratic

Using IBM CPLEX, I'm struggling to run a MILP file, on the constraints I would like to add the following line:

`Subject to
a_1 P_1 + 22.62 b_2 + a_2 P_2 + 24.87 b_2 - P_3 + A = 0`

For this case CPLEX runs, but in some cases some variables are "glued" (truncated), like that:

`<variable name "a_1P_1" index="63" value"0" reducedCost="3.71741848184e-06"/>`

Trying to solve this problem of "stuck variables", I decided to put an asterisk (*) to represent the multiplication of the two unknown variables, such as:

`Subject to
a_1*P_1 + 22.62 b_2 + a_2*P_2 + 24.87 b_2 - P_3 + A = 0`

But in this case the CPLEX returns an error:

`CPLEX Error 1608: Line 7:Expected '+','-' or sense, found '*'.`

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to solve an [MIQCP](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.2/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/discr_optim/mip_quadratic/03_introMIQCP.html?lang=en).

In the documentation for [LP file format: algebraic representation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.2/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/FileFormats/topics/LP.html?lang=en), we have the following:

> Quadratic constraints are allowed in this section. Quadratic terms are
>   specified inside square brackets [] ....

In the section on Quadratic terms it says you can use asterisk (*) and the caret (^) inside the square brackets.